# unicode normalization: dotless i + accent

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

Let's combine a regular `i` with a combining acute accent, and normalize the result (using Python's [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)):

```py
from unicodedata import normalize

normalize("NFC", "i\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}").encode("ascii", "namereplace")
```

```
b'\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE}'
```

As expected: a small `i` with the dot swapped out for an acute accent, `í`.

Let's do the same with a dotless i:

```py
from unicodedata import normalize

normalize("NFC", "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}").encode("ascii", "namereplace")
```

```
b'\\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I}\\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}'
```

As you can see, it does *not* combine. Other implementations, e.g., [this one](https://www.minaret.info/test/normalize.msp), do the same.

Why not? Is this consistent with [the Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/?win)?

Comment: There *is* no separate Unicode character for an accented dotless `i`. Precomposed code points like `LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE` are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: The whole reason `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT` exists is that it would be infeasible to define every possible composition of characters as a separate code point. The combining characters let renderers generate such compositions as and when needed.

Comment: Why can't the combination be the `LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE`? Is there a rule that the combination map needs to be injective, i.e., unique?

Comment: I presume so, as it would allow to losslessly roundtrip through NFC and NFD forms, but I'm not sure (ie. I'm too lazy to search for the information on unicode.org). On the other hand, the NFK* forms *are* lossy, so I don't know if we can expect NFC/NFD conversions to be lossless.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer the point is to allow [lossless round-trip conversion from/to legacy encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_format_conversion#Character_encodings). That's why you see there are Unicode code points for "silly" characters such as ǋ,  ǲ, Ⅷ, ㍴, ㎓, ﷽... So if there are no accented dotless i in use then there won't be a Unicode character for it

Comment: In fact this happened with Vietnamese in the early Unicode days when the Unicode committee didn't agree to add precomposed Vietnamese characters, and a group named Viet-Std was so angry that they created their own encoding. The job was so successful that in 1993 precomposed Vietnamese characters were added to Unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [The Unicode Standard, Version 14.0](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch07.pdf#page=6), *Diacritics on i and j* (highlighting by myself):

> A dotted (normal) i or j followed by some common nonspacing
> marks above loses the dot in rendering. Thus, in the word naïve, the ï could be spelled with
> i + diaeresis. A dotted-i is not equivalent to a Turkish dotless-i + overdot, **nor are other cases
> of accented dotted-i equivalent to accented dotless-i** (for example, i + ¨ ≠ ı + ¨).